# How to programmatically cause a core dump in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, coredump, abort

I would like to force a core dump at a specific location in my C++ application.

I know I can do it by doing something like:

```
int * crash = NULL;
*crash = 1;
```

But I would like to know if there is a cleaner way?

I am using Linux by the way.

Comment: BTW, that method doesn't work in all UNIXes. HPUX, for one, allows you to read and write NULL with impunity (thankfully, this is configurable).

Comment: @pax thats more of a reason to find a generic way ;) Thanks

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Raising of signal  number 6 (`SIGABRT` in Linux) is one way to do it (though keep in mind that SIGABRT is not *required* to be 6 in all POSIX implementations so you may want to use the `SIGABRT` value itself if this is anything other than quick'n'dirty debug code).

```
#include <signal.h>
: : :
raise (SIGABRT);
```

Calling `abort()` will also cause a core dump, and you can even do this *without* terminating your process by calling `fork()` followed by `abort()` in the child only - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/131539/60462) for details.

Comment: SIGABRT is not required to be signal number 6 (though it often is - and is, specifically, on Linux).

Comment: No, you're right, it's not but I tend not to worry too much about the correctness of debug code. If that escapes into the wild, the cleanliness of my code is the least of my worries :-)

Comment: Calling abort() may be useless on some architectures with some compilers and some C libraries (like gcc and glibc or uClibc on ARM) because the abort() function is declared with a __noreturn__ attribute and the compiler totally optimizes out all the return information, which makes the core file unusable. You can't trace it past the call to raise() or abort() itself.

So it is much better to call raise(SIGABRT) directly or kill(getpid(), SIGABRT), which is virtually the same.

Comment: Sorry, on ARM the same thing happens even with raise(SIGABRT). So the only way to produce a traceable core file is __kill(getpid(), SIGABRT)__

Comment: The hint to `ulimit -c unlimited` from Suvesh Pratapa answer, helped my a lot for this answer.

Answer (score 79):

A few years ago, Google released the [coredumper](http://code.google.com/p/google-coredumper/) library.

> ## Overview
>
> The coredumper library can be compiled into applications to create core dumps of the running program -- without terminating. It supports both single- and multi-threaded core dumps, even if the kernel does not natively support multi-threaded core files.
>
> Coredumper is distributed under the terms of the BSD License.
>
> ## Example
>
> This is by no means a complete example; it simply gives you a feel for what the coredumper API looks like.
>
> ```
> #include <google/coredumper.h>
> ...
> WriteCoreDump('core.myprogram');
> /* Keep going, we generated a core file,
>  * but we didn't crash.
>  */
> ```

It's not what you were asking for, but maybe it's even better :)

Comment: I was initially pretty excited when I ran across this answer. But core dumper is looking pretty old and decrepit these days. There's even indication that it doesn't work anymore on contemporary Linux kernels: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314020/google-coredumper-returns-operation-not-permitted

Answer (score 41):

As listed in the [signal manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), any signal with the action listed as 'core' will force a core dump. Some examples are:

```
SIGQUIT       3       Core    Quit from keyboard
SIGILL        4       Core    Illegal Instruction
SIGABRT       6       Core    Abort signal from abort(3)
SIGFPE        8       Core    Floating point exception
SIGSEGV      11       Core    Invalid memory reference
```

Make sure that you enable core dumps:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Comment: Thanks, your remark about enabling core dumps with `ulimit -c unlimited` helped.

Comment: How would you set the ulimit from within the code? @ks1322

Comment: @KaranJoisher That's probably worth of another question unto itself, but in short you can use `setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &core_limits);` available via `#include <sys/resource.h>`.  You create a struct of type `rlimit` and then set the `rlim_cur` and `rlim_max` members.

Answer (score 34):

```
#include <stdlib.h>   // C
//#include <cstdlib>  // C++

void core_dump(void)
{
    abort();
}
```

Comment: Why not just call `abort()` directly?

Answer (score 13):

Invoke

```
abort();
```

Related, sometimes you'd like a back trace without an actual core dump, and allow the program to continue running:  check out glibc backtrace() and backtrace_symbols() functions:
http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html

Answer (score 7):

Another way of generating a core dump:

```
$ bash
$ kill -s SIGSEGV $$
```

Just create a new instance of the bash and kill it with specified signal. The `$$` is the PID of
the shell. Otherwise you are killing your current bash and will be logged out, terminal closed or disconnected.

```
$ bash 
$ kill -s SIGABRT $$
$ bash
$ kill -s SIGFPE $$
```

Comment: Very simple and useful!

Comment: I like that one, too. It can even be simplified to `bash -c 'kill -SIGSEGV $$'`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [kill(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) to send signal.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);
```

So,

```
kill(getpid(), SIGSEGV);
```

Comment: Yup. Added that to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it may be appropriate to do something like this:

```
int st = 0;
pid_t p = fork();

if (!p) {
    signal(SIGABRT, SIG_DFL);
    abort(); // having the coredump of the exact copy of the calling thread
} else {
    waitpid(p, &st, 0); // rip the zombie
}

// here the original process continues to live
```

One problem with this simple approach is that only one thread will be coredumped.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 int main()
 {
   printf("\n");
   printf("Process is aborting\n");
   abort();
   printf("Control not reaching here\n");
   return 0;
 }
```

use this approach wherever you want :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <assert.h>
.
.
.
     assert(!"this should not happen");
```

Comment: Probably need to muck with NDEBUG so this particular assert is active even when other asserts are not.