# GDB creating a core file

Tags: c, gdb, coredump

For testing purposes I want to create a core file of a test program I made. It's not corrupted and it doesn't screw up, but I want to generate a core file of it. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
printf("TEST");
}
```

How can I create a core dump of it?
BTW I'm on Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Do want to do this by change the program itself or externally?

Comment: Do you want to change the program so it generates a core dump, or do you want to keep the program the same and trigger the core dump externally?

Comment: I want to trigger the core dump externally.

Comment: you could `kill -SEGV <pid>` to simulate a segmentation fault.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programatically cause a core dump in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979141/how-to-programatically-cause-a-core-dump-in-c-c)

Comment: How could I find the PID of the program? I've looked on TOP's list but its not there.

Comment: @Jack Jacobsen: It's probably not there any more. Your program will exit fast.

Answer (score 12):

From the gdb command prompt with your executable loaded, issue the `generate-core-file` command.

Comment: +1, but should note that this isn't supported on Windows (at least without Cygwin) for whatever reason.

Comment: Ugh... GCC 6.6 on OpenBSD: *`Undefined command: "generate-core-file".  Try "help".`*

Answer (score 6):

<strike>If you can change the program adding a call to `abort()` will generate a core dump in many unix environments.</strike>

You need to make sure that you have core files enabled. The most common reason for core files not being generated is a zero size core **ulimit**. Check with the command `ulimit -c` and reset if zero with `ulimit -c unlimited`.

If you don't want to change the program you can send an abort signal with the kill command: `kill -SIGABRT <pid>` but with such a short program you are probably going to have to used a script and even then you may not be able to get the signal in before the process exits.

With bash you can try something like this (assuming that your program is called `a.out` and is in the current directory):

```
./a.out & kill -SIGABRT $!
```

`&` says run this in the background and `$!` is the PID of the most recently executed background command.

Comment: (-1) Is it possible that the application exit before the SIGABRT signal is send? You would need a sleep() or scanf() to wait for.

Comment: @Raphael B.: Yes, this is what I said: "even then you may not be able to get the signal in before the process exits". I'm not sure I understand your (-1) explanation?

Answer (score 6):

Load your program in gdb, set a breakpoint, run to the break point and then

> (gdb) generate-core-file

Comment: Ugh... GCC 6.6 on OpenBSD: *`Undefined command: "generate-core-file".  Try "help".`*

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use - `gcore` command.