# Generating thread dump of C++ process

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, memory-management, memory-leaks

I would like to debug and identify a memory leak in one/some of the threads in a C++ process.
I would like to get a thread dump of the process once the memory usage is very high.

I know for java the following commands work, 'kill -3 ' [linux] or 'sendsignal.exe  ' (http://www.latenighthacking.com/projects/2003/sendSignal/)

Is there any way to a get thread dump for C++ process on Windows.

can this thread be related:
[How to programmatically cause a core dump in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979141/how-to-programatically-cause-a-core-dump-in-c-c)

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Minidump, not "thread dump".  It is built into Taskmgr.exe for Vista and Win7.  Right-click the process in the Processes tab, Create Dump File.  All the different ways are [listed here](https://www.wintellect.com/how-to-capture-a-minidump-let-me-count-the-ways/).

Answer (score 1):

You can also generate memory dumps (mini-dumps) based on performance counters (handle count, memory consumption) automatically using procdump from SysInternals: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900

You can then load and analyze the generated file(s) in WinDbg (or in VS2010 which can now also load memory dumps)