# google-coredumper returns Operation not permitted

Tags: c++

Background: Downloaded google-coredumper-1.2.1.tar.gz from code.google.com. built the code and make install. Added library and function call to my application and execute. No core file, Logs state Operation not permitted. So I created a simple example and stepped through it and found that the library believes that the executable is already being traced. Any ideas?

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "crashtest.h"
#include <google/coredumper.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

FILE    * backtrace_file = NULL;

#define SIZE 100

void CREATE_COREDUMP()
{
  printf("NOTICE, Creating a core dump for debugging\n");
  char    extension[64];
  time_t  t       = time((time_t*)NULL);
  tm    * theTime = localtime(&t);

  snprintf( extension,
          sizeof(extension) - 1,
          "core.crashtest_02d_%02d_%02d_%02d", (theTime->tm_mday),
                                               (theTime->tm_hour),
                                               (theTime->tm_min) ,
                                               (theTime->tm_sec) );
  if (WriteCoreDump(extension) != 0) {
    std::string errmsg(extension);
    errmsg.append(" : ");
    errmsg.append(strerror(errno));
    printf("WARNING, Failed to create coredump: %s\n", errmsg.c_str() );
  }
}

static void mysighandler(int sig)
{
  printf("ERROR, Somebody Segmentation Faulted. About to Exit\n");

  CREATE_COREDUMP();
  exit(0);
}

crashtest::crashtest() {
  char * errcond = NULL;
  memcpy(errcond, "Crash This", 10);
}

crashtest::~crashtest() {}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  struct sigaction sa;

  sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_handler = &mysighandler;

  sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);

  crashtest ct;
  return 0;
}
```

The point of the exercise is that the main code generates a segmentation fault occasionally which does not make sense because all the values are initialized. Therefore I am trying to discover why there is a segmentation fault and would like to get a core to track down the offending line of code. I cannot just kill since the code is required to recover and continue. That is why google-coredumper is thought to be used.

Comment: Debugger does indeed trace the program, so the library was right in its beliefs. I am afraid it has nothing to do with "Operation not permitted". Check output of `ulimit -c`, and  if it is 0, set it to the reasonable value.

Comment: core dumps are enabled. I had put a print statement at the location that the debugger flagged and even when not stepping through the code the line was printed. There appears to be another object tracing the threads.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/622686, it seems that coredumper in its current state is not usable anymore:

> I believe, if I interpret the data on kernel.org correctly, this
>   change  was made by Linus and shipped with 2.6.15.
>
> Both perftools and coredumper need to locate all threads in the active
>   application in order to work. As libpthread has had changing and
>   poorly  documented APIs to get this information, and as our intent is
>   to support  all kernel versions and all libc versions, we resorted to
>   ptracing any  process that is suspected to be one of our threads in
>   order to determine  if it actually is. This has the added benefit of
>   finding *all* threads  (including ones not managed by libpthread) and
>   of temporarily suspending  them, so that we have a stable memory image
>   that we can inspect. Think  of both tools as something like a
>   lightweight in-process debugger.
>
> Obviously, special care has to be taken to not ptrace our own thread, 
>   and to avoid any library calls that could deadlock.
>
> Before the patch, attaching ptrace to my own threads was a valid 
>   operation. With this new patch, I can no longer do that.