# Is it possible to peridocally save state of the program through a core dump?

Tags: linux, debugging, coredump

I just want to dump core without stopping the program.
This would be essentialy serializing a whole state of the program.
A very convenient thing for debugging later.

Is it possible under linux?

Comment: This is actually a duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131439/how-can-a-c-program-produce-a-core-dump-of-itself-without-terminating

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found simple solution:

```
$gcore
usage:  gcore [-o filename] pid
```

It is distributed with gdb.

Comment: That looks like the kind of program I've wanted for years!  Much more reliable than kill -11 :-)  Thanks Łukasz!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is exactly what you want (unless you *want* to pause the program while inspecting, or even modify the memory), but have a look at [CryoPID](http://cryopid.berlios.de/).

Answer (score 1):

Even better!!!
[Gdb 7.0](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/news/) have support for reversible debugging.
And it was released yesterday, what a coincidence :D

Answer (score 0):

should be doable, at least /proc//smaps contains information of the process memory and the actual memory should be accessible via /dev/mem

I think you need to suspend the process to avoid corruption of the captured info, though.