# generate core from C program on Solaris

Tags: c, solaris

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can a C program produce a core dump of itself without terminating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131439/how-can-a-c-program-produce-a-core-dump-of-itself-without-terminating)

I would like to generate a core from a C program without terminating the running process.
OS is Solaris.

I know that gcore can be used for this purpose. But I have no idea how to use 'gcore' from a C program.

Comment: Does this need to be done programatically? You can attach in gdb and run the command generate-core-file to get a core.

Comment: I don't want the program to end prematurely , I want it to run ,but would like to capture core at a particular line while continuing its flow. btw, I can't use gdb too, because it occurs in a production environment. I can only change the code and copy the execs to prod m/c, run the program and check the core dump.

Comment: Ex: gencore() on AIX is described here at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.basetechref%2Fdoc%2Fbasetrf1%2Fgencore.htm, I am looking for a similar way of programming on solaris..

Answer (score 1):

`gcore` is implemented in C and the source is [available](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/cmd/gcore/gcore.c), so it's obviously possible to replicate what it does. However, looking at the source reveals that it makes use of the semi-private `libproc` library, whose coredump generating code is fairly convoluted.

It seems the best option to simply invoke `gcore` using `system(3)` or some of its variants:

```
int gcore(pid_t pid) 
{
  char *cmd[256];
  snprintf(cmd, sizeof cmd, "gcore %ld", (long) pid);
  // returns 0 on success, -1 on system failure (errno set), or >0 on
  // gcore failure (in which case use the W* macros defined in
  // <sys/wait.h> to extract additional information from value).
  return system(cmd);
}
```

[(Link to `<sys/wait.h>` docs.)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29033/wait.h-3head.html#REFMAN3Fwait.h-3head)