# Fork and core dump with threads

Tags: c++, c, linux, pthreads, coredump

Similar points to the one in this question have been raised before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/131439/596781) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/979141/596781), and I'm aware of the Google coredump library (which I've appraised and found lacking, though I might try and work on that if I understand the problem better).

I want to obtain a core dump of a running Linux process without interrupting the process. The natural approach is to say:

```
if (!fork()) { abort(); }
```

Since the forked process gets a fixed snapshot copy of the original process's memory, I should get a complete core dump, and since the copy uses copy-on-write, it should generally be cheap. However, a critical shortcoming of this approach is that `fork()` only forks the current thread, and all other threads of the original process won't exist in the forked copy.

My question is whether it is possible to somehow obtain the relevant data of the other, original threads. I'm not entirely sure how to approach this problem, but here are a couple of sub-questions I've come up with:

1. Is the memory that contains all of the threads' stacks still available and accessible in the forked process?
2. Is it possible to (quicky) enumerate all the running threads in the original process and store the addresses of the bases of their stacks? As I understand it, the base of a thread stack on Linux contains a pointer to the kernel's thread bookkeeping data, so...
3. with the stored thread base addresses, could you read out the relevant data for each of the original threads in the forked process?

If that is possible, perhaps it would only be a matter of appending the data of the other threads to the core dump. However, if that data is lost at the point of the fork already, then there doesn't seem to be any hope for this approach.

Comment: I don't now of any enumarion feature in pthreads... - but regarding `fork()`ing you might like to look at `pthread_atfork()`. It seem that using handlers registered by the latter could be used to roll ones own pthread-enumerator.

Comment: Maybe the reason that why it only forks the current thread is the implementation of thread in Linux, it uses `clone()`.

Comment: @Marcus: I wasn't really worried about *why* `fork()` behaves the way it does. I'm quite happy with what it does, which seems sane to me.

Comment: [This article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/kevgrig/entry/ibm_java_on_linux_avoid_using_gcore?lang=en) about IBM's Java producing a core dump with fork+signal says they're using information in `/proc/PID/maps` to retrieve information "that wouldn't otherwise be there".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you familiar with process checkpoint-restart? In particular, [CRIU](http://criu.org/Main_Page)? It seems to me it might provide an easy option for you.

> I want to obtain a core dump of a running Linux process without interrupting the process [and] to somehow obtain the relevant data of the other, original threads.

Forget about not interrupting the process. If you think about it, a core dump *has to* interrupt the process for the duration of the dump; your true goal must therefore be to minimize the duration of this interruption. Your original idea of using `fork()` does interrupt the process, it just does so for a very short time.

> 1. Is the memory that contains all of the threads' stacks still available and accessible in the forked process?

No. The `fork()` only retains the thread that does the actual call, and the stacks for the rest of the threads are lost.

Here is the procedure I'd use, assuming CRIU is unsuitable:

- Have a parent process that generates a core dump of the child process whenever the child is stopped. (Note that more than one consecutive stop event may be generated; only the first one until the next continue event should be acted on.)

  You can detect the stop/continue events using [`waitpid(child,,WUNTRACED|WCONTINUED)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html).
- Optional: Use [`sched_setaffinity()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html) to restrict the process to a single CPU, and [`sched_setscheduler()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html) (and perhaps [`sched_setparam()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setparam.2.html)) to drop the process priority to `IDLE`.

  You can do this from the parent process, which only needs the `CAP_SYS_NICE` capability (which you can give it using `setcap 'cap_sys_nice=pe' parent-binary` to the parent binary, if you have filesystem capabilities enabled like most current Linux distributions do), in both the effective and permitted sets.

  The intent is to minimize the progress of the other threads between the moment a thread decides it wants a snapshot/dump, and the moment when all threads have been stopped. I have not tested how long it takes for the changes to take effect -- certainly they only happen at the end of their current timeslices at the very earliest. So, this step should probably be done a bit beforehand.

  Personally, I don't bother. On my four-core machine, the following `SIGSTOP` alone yields similar latencies between threads as a mutex or a semaphore does, so I don't see any need to strive for even better synchronization.
- When a thread in the child process decides it wants to take a snapshot of itself, it sends a `SIGSTOP` to itself (via `kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP)`). This stops all threads in the process.

  The parent process will receive the notification that the child was stopped. It will first examines `/proc/PID/task/` to obtain the TIDs for each thread of the child process (and perhaps `/proc/PID/task/TID/` pseudofiles for other information), then attaches to each TID using [`ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, TID)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html). Obviously, [`ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, TID, ...)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) will obtain the per-thread register states, which can be used in conjunction with `/proc/PID/task/TID/smaps` and `/proc/PID/task/TID/mem` to obtain the per-thread stack trace, and whatever other information you're interested in. (For example, you could create a debugger-compatible core file for each thread.)

  When the parent process is done grabbing the dump, it lets the child process continue. I believe you need to send a separate `SIGCONT` signal to let the entire child process continue, instead of just relying on `ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, TID)`, but I haven't checked this; do verify this, please.

I do believe that the above will yield a minimal delay in wall clock time between the threads in the process stopping. Quick tests on AMD Athlon II X4 640 on Xubuntu and a 3.8.0-29-generic kernel indicates tight loops incrementing a volatile variable in the other threads only advance the counters by a few thousand, depending on the number of threads (there's too much noise in the few tests I made to say anything more specific).

Limiting the process to a single CPU, and even to IDLE priority, will drastically reduce that delay even further. `CAP_SYS_NICE` capability allows the parent to not only reduce the priority of the child process, but also lift the priority back to original levels; filesystem capabilities mean the parent process does not even have to be setuid, as `CAP_SYS_NICE` alone suffices. (I think it'd be safe enough -- with some good checks in the parent program -- to be installed in e.g. university computers, where students are quite active in finding interesting ways to exploit the installed programs.)

It is possible to create a kernel patch (or module) that provides a boosted `kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP)` that also tries to kick off the other threads from running CPUs, and thus try to make the delay between the threads stopping even smaller. Personally, I wouldn't bother. Even without the CPU/priority manipulation I get sufficient synchronization (small enough delays between the times the threads are stopped).

Do you need some example code to illustrate my ideas above?

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm working on this (and your other answer), and I'll be sure to be back with questions!

Comment: Here's a question: I want to reverse the parent-child relationship in the setup and have the child do the tracing, dumping and dying. So: is it possible to send SIGSTOP (consistently) to a process that is not your own child? Is there a way to `wait` for a process that is not your child?

Comment: Never mind: I found that you *can* wait for any process that's being traced, and the tracee becomes a quasi-child for the duration of the trace.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Quite right, you can wait for any process you are tracing. Also note that Ubuntu et al. does not by default allow a child process to trace its parent, unless the traced process calls `prctl(PR_SET_PTRACER,..)` or the tracer has the `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` capability. (You can use `sudo setcap 'cap_sys_ptrace=pe' tracer-binary` to give the tracer program that via file capabilities.)

Answer (score 2):

When you `fork` you get a full copy of the running processes memory. This includes all thread's stacks (after all you could have valid pointers into them). But only the calling thread continues to execute in the child.

You can easily test this. Make a multithreaded program and run:

```
pid_t parent_pid = getpid();

if (!fork()) {
    kill(parent_pid, SIGSTOP);

    char buffer[0x1000];

    pid_t child_pid = getpid();
    sprintf(buffer, "diff /proc/%d/maps /proc/%d/maps", parent_pid, child_pid);

    system(buffer);

    kill(parent_pid, SIGTERM);

    return 0;
} else for (;;);
```

So all your memory is there and when you create a core dump it will contain all the other threads stacks (provided your maximum core file size permits it). The only pieces that will be missing are their register sets. If you need those then you will have to `ptrace` your parent to obtain them.

You should keep in mind though that core dumps are not designed to contain runtime information of more then one thread - the one that caused the core dump.

To answer some of your other questions:

You can enumerate threads by going through `/proc/[pid]/tasks`, but you can not identify their stack bases until you `ptrace` them.

Yes, you have full access to the other threads stacks snapshots (see above) from the forked process. It is not trivial to determine them, but they do get put into a core dump provided the core file size permits it. Your best bet is to save them in some globally accessible structure if you can upon creation.

Comment: The problem with going through `/proc/pid/tasks` is that it isn't synchronized to the core dump, since I can't stop the parent's threads...

Comment: @KerrekSB You can: `kill(parent_pid, SIGSTOP)`

Comment: But that's not *synchronized*. The parent will have gone off and have a different memory content by the time I send the signal, and more importantly, by the time the signal is delivered to all the threads.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to get the core file at non-specific location, and just get core image of the process running without killing, then you can use [gcore](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/gcore-man.html).

If you intend to get the core file at specific location (condition) and still continue running the process - a crude approach is to execute [gcore](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/gcore-man.html) programmatically from that location.

A more classical, clean approach would be to check the API which gcore uses and embedded it in your application - but would be too much of an effort compared to the need most of the time.

HTH!

Comment: How does `gcore` ensure that the process keeps running?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Read the [man](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?topic=gcore) page. The option `-s` "Stop the process while gathering the core image, and resume it when done. This guarantees that the resulting core dump will be in a consistent state. The process is resumed even if it was already stopped. The same effect can be achieved manually with kill(1)"

Comment: @Linuxios: Hm, that's for BSD. I think I should have said I want a Linux solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to snapshot the entire process in order to understand the exact state of all threads at a specific point then I can't see any way to do this that doesn't require some kind of interrupt service routine.  You must halt all processors and record off the current state of each thread.

I don't know of any system that provides this kind of full process core dump.  The rough outlines of the process would be:

1. issue an interrupt across all CPUs (both logical and physical cores).
2. busy wait for all cores to synchronize (this shouldn't take long).
3. clone the desired process's memory space: duplicate the page tables and mark all pages as copy on write.
4. have each processor check whether its current thread is in the target process.  If so record the current stack pointer for that thread.
5. for every other thread examine the thread data block for the current stack pointer and record it.
6. create a kernel thread to save off the copied memory spaces and the thread stack pointers
7. resume all cores.

This should capture the entire process state, including a snapshot of any processes that were running at the moment the inter-processor interrupt was issued.  Because all threads are interrupted (either through standard scheduler suspension process, or via our custom interrupt process) all register states will be on a stack somewhere in the process memory.  You then only need to know where the top of each thread stack is.  Using the copy on write mechanism to clone the page tables allows transparent save-off while the original process is allowed to resume.

This is a pretty heavyweight option, since it's main functionality requires suspending all processors for a significant amount of time (synchronize, clone, walk all threads).  However this should allow you to exactly capture the status of all threads, as well as determine which threads were running (and on which CPUs) when the checkpoint was reached.  I would assume some of the framework for doing this process exists (in CRIU for instance).  Of course resuming the process will result in a storm of page allocations as the copy on write mechanism protects the check-pointed system state.