# Capture state of a paused C++/C program for future reference

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu

Is it possible to pause a running program in C/C++ and capture its state which can be used later to resume it from the breakpoint?

Comment: Maybe with [criu](http://criu.org/Main_Page)?

Comment: @KerrekSB That's awesome.

Comment: @H2CO3: Credit goes to Nominal Animal who [showed me that project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18581317/596781).

Comment: You should tag what platform (OS) you are need a solution for.

Comment: Another available solution is http://crd.lbl.gov/groups-depts/ftg/projects/current-projects/BLCR

Comment: Maybe you want to do this at a higher abstraction level? Maybe the perspective changes a bit if you give a hint to your specific use case.

Comment: Note that there is no way to resume a program with a socket, unless the other side of the socket is also willing to resume at the same time.